# MySQL - HOUR(Datetime)

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have an error in this query. The error says *Expected known function, got 'HOUR'*. The query works right if I remove this part (`AND HOUR({$nowDate}) = 11`)

```
SELECT c FROM ProConvocationBundle:Convocation c
INNER JOIN ProCommunityBundle:Community co WITH co.id = c.community
INNER JOIN ProProposalBundle:Proposal p WITH p.convocation = c.id
WHERE c.firstNotificationAfterConvocation = FALSE
AND c.status <> 'finished' AND c.date >= {$minDate} AND HOUR({$nowDate}) = 11
```

Both `$nowDate` and `$minDate` are `Datetime` format.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which database product are you using (SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc...)?

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 - Yes, sorry. MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

*edit after your comment:*

If `$dateTime` is just a string formatted as `2014-04-11 08:38:00` and you want the hour, you can use this:

```
echo date('H', strtotime($nowDate))
```

If `$nowDate` a [PHP DateTime object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), you can use the followin

```
echo $nowDate->format('H');
```

It has nothing to do with MySQL :)

Comment: Thanks, but I just want to check if `$nowDate` hour is 11. Nothing to do with `c.date`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you need to convert $nowDate to `String` because `HOUR` function needs String as param:

```
SELECT c FROM ProConvocationBundle:Convocation c
INNER JOIN ProCommunityBundle:Community co WITH co.id = c.community
INNER JOIN ProProposalBundle:Proposal p WITH p.convocation = c.id
WHERE c.firstNotificationAfterConvocation = FALSE
AND c.status <> 'finished' AND c.date >= {$minDate} AND HOUR({$nowDate->format('H:i:s')}) = 11
```

This should work